# ogr2ogr in QGIS v3.8 vs. v3.20 - swapped coordinates from swissgrid to WGS84 when import to MariaDB 10.4.19-

Tags: qgis, coordinates, ogr2ogr, mariadb

I have a shapefile to be imported to db. in QGIS 3.8 the following worked:

```
ogr2ogr -f ....... -t_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=neu +wktext"
```

but with the latest QGIS 3.20 coordinates are in the wrong order:
`'POLYGON((8.62661151165165 46.8970840194569....'` instead of `'POLYGON((46.8970840194569 8.62661151165165...'`

What do I miss?

Comment: It may be related to this GDAL change (read carefully): https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html#crs-and-axis-order

Comment: try with `-t_srs epsg:4326`

Comment: What is the EPSG code of the source CRS? Give one coordinate pair in the source system. What is to target database? How did you generate the WKT for the polygon?

Comment: This is what in QGIS 3.8 worked:    ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:name,host=name,user=username,password=pwd name.shp -nln dbname -update -append -lco engine=MYISAM -skipfailures -t_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=neu +wktext"    i had to update to QGIS 3.20 because now i need engine=INNODB the EPSG of the source is 2056

Comment: INNODB does not seem to be documented https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mysql.html. Have you tried `+axis=enu`?

Comment: yes, I tried +axis=enu and -t_srs epsg:4326 with no success :(

Comment: Please edit the title and tags to mention MySQL and add the db version into the body of your question. MySQL users will find your question easier. I am quite sure that the problem is with the MySQL driver. Conversion into PostGIS, GeoPackage and other formats would probably success. Notice that most programs consider that WKT is always longitude-latitude. MySQL since version 8 considers that with EPSG:4326 even WKT must be latitude-longitude.

Comment: I tried on a MariaDB 10.4 DB and now also on MySQL 5.7.26-log-cll-lve - both still with wrong order of coordinates.

Comment: Hi, try to export to OGC:CRS84 (-t_srs OGC:CRS84), it is the SRID=4326 in most database engines.

Comment: We should know more details on what you do and how the error appears. If you are in Switzerland for most GIS programs the WKT `POLYGON((8.62661151165165 46.8970840194569` is right (longitude before latitude). MySQL before version 8 and MariaDB belong to the lon-lat league. Do your data appear in wrong place on the QGIS map once saved into database?

Comment: Dear user30184 - yes it is synoptic hazard area from switzerland. Up to now all imported data was ordered lat-lon and for MySQL 5.7/MariaDB 10.4 geo-functions like st_intersects,... lat-lon is required (as far as I understand). So basically I have a compatibility-problem?